# youtube-dl + ffmpeg: Import description and URL of an original video to ID3 tags

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube-dl, id3

Following bundle is used to download and encode audio:

```
/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl --playlist-reverse -o "%(upload_date)s %(title)s.%(ext)s" --write-annotations --download-archive ".archive" --add-metadata --write-sub --sub-lang en --write-auto-sub -f "bestaudio[ext=m4a]" -i "https://www.youtube.com/channel/CHANNEL_ID"
for name in *.m4a; do
  /usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -loglevel info -i "$name" -metadata artist="ArtistName" -metadata album="AlbumName" -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -ac 1 -ab 192k "${name%.*}_192.mp3"
done
```

When the resulting file is viewed in a hex viewer, the description of the original video can be viewed in binary form, but when the file is loaded in Tag&Rename 3.5.5, there is nothing in the standard "Description" ID3 tag.

Also the standard "URL" ID3 tag is neither shown in Tag&Rename nor present in a binary form.

How to import both, description and URL, to the right places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use webm, not m4a

The M4A muxer won't include URL metadata, so your MP3 command didn't have it to begin with.

Use WebM instead. In `youtube-dl` use `-f "bestaudio[ext=webm]"` instead of `-f "bestaudio[ext=m4a]"`

So now the URL metadata will be included. However, that only partially solves the URL and comment/description metadata issue.

## ffmpeg MP3 metadata is weird

For some reason `ffmpeg` uses *User defined text information frame* (TXXX) for comments/description and URL instead of the proper tag identifier. So although the metadata is there your player/tagger may ignore it.

I'm not aware of a tool that allows you to reassign existing tags, so consider asking at [softwarerecs.stackexchange.com](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Otherwise, you'll have to do it manually by using a tool such as `eyeD3` after encoding the MP3 with `ffmpeg` using metadata from the WebM file:

```
eyeD3 --user-url-frame ":$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format_tags=PURL -of csv=p=0 "input.webm")" --add-comment "$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format_tags=DESCRIPTION -of csv=p=0 "input.webm")" --remove-frame TXXX input.mp3
```

**Update**

In eyeD3 command line parameters colons should be properly escaped, otherwise they will be recognized as a delimiters:

```
#!/bin/bash
name="f.webm"
# Get the URL
video_url=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format_tags=PURL -of csv=p=0 "$name")
# Replace ":" with "\:"
video_url="${video_url//:/\:}"
# Write the URL
eyeD3 --user-url-frame ":$video_url" "${name%.*}.mp3"
```

**Update 2**

if description text is empty `eyeD3` raises an exception and won't do any tasks that should be executed after this step. I looked into its source code - this behaviour is by design so and couldn't be turned off with some command line switches. It means that each operation should be performed separately after checking that corresponding variable is not empty:

```
if [[ ! -z "$video_url" ]]
then
  # Run eyeD3 only if variable is not empty because eyeD3 raises an exception and will not do any other tasks that might succeed
  eyeD3 --user-url-frame ":$video_url" "${name%.*}.mp3"
fi
if [[ ! -z "$video_dsc" ]]
then
  # Run eyeD3 only if variable is not empty because eyeD3 raises an exception and will not do any other tasks that might succeed
  eyeD3 --add-comment "$video_dsc" "${name%.*}.mp3"
fi
eyeD3 --remove-frame TXXX "${name%.*}.mp3"
```

Comment: @Paul Works for me: `ffprobe -v error -show_entries format_tags=PURL -of csv=p=0 input.webm` shows `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<id>`

Comment: @Paul Did you try `ffprobe`?

Comment: @Paul Using the same input you get different results on Windows vs CentOS? Your edit was rejected before I could look at it, but feel free to make it a new answer. I'll take your word for the eyeD3 behavior. At this point you're more familiar with it than I am.

Comment: @Paul https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/1055490

Comment: Thank you very much. The reviewer was wrong in a very unprofessional way. My text doesn't make sense as a stand-alone answer. It is a complement to make your answer work. And yes, I am using the same command line for both, Windows and Linux.

Comment: @Paul I approved the edit, but I did not test any of the commands.