# MP3 - copy one ID3 tag to another

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, id3

How to copy `PURL` tag to `URL` using ffmpeg or some other command line tool?

OS: Windows 7 or CentOS 7. Ideally should work on both.

The program where I see the "URL" named field is either Tag&Rename for Windows or ffmpeg or MPC HC. In raw hex view it doesn't have any string identifier.

The program where I see the "PURL" named field is ffmpeg or any raw hex viewer.

Comment: Right now, the is likely to be closed since you're asking multiple things. We generally only want one question, one answer here so it's easier for people who encounter the questions in the future. You can [edit] your question to remove the one you don't want to ask here.

Comment: Which program do the "URL" and "PURL" names come from? Which OS do you have available? I'm going to suggest python-mutagen for things that don't necessarily have an existing CLI tool...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FFmpeg MP3 muxer does not support all ID3v2 tags including URL related tags (`WXXX`, `WCOM`, `WOAR` frames).

Use another tool such as `eyeD3`:

```
eyeD3 --user-url-frame ":$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format_tags=PURL -of csv=p=0 "source_file.foo")" input.mp3
```

Comment: For corrections of the answer please look here: https://superuser.com/questions/1587534/youtube-dl-ffmpeg-import-description-and-url-of-an-original-video-to-id3-tags/1588252#1588252