# Prepend MP3 ID3 title tag with time stamp

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3

I am downloading channel audios with following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
...............
youtube-dl -o "%(upload_date)s %(title)s.%(ext)s" --write-annotations --download-archive "$ArchiveFile" --add-metadata --write-sub --sub-lang ru --write-auto-sub --sub-format srt -f "bestaudio[ext=webm]" -i "$ChannelPath"
```

With these parameters file names are written in following format:

```
yyyymmdd Corrected video title text.webm
```

After that I convert WEBM to MP3 with `ffmpeg` which takes over all the tags from WEBM file.

I would like that not only the file name, but also title written to ID3 tag is prepended with `yyyymmdd`  time stamp, too. I could take some tool and write file name into corresponding ID3 tag.

The problem is that title in ID3 tag fully corresponds to video title and file name is a corrected title, with removed forbidden characters.

How to take the MP3 title from ID3 title tag and prepend it with time stamp?

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert the WebM to MP3 with `ffmpeg`:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i input.webm -map 0:a output.mp3
   ```
2. Use `ffprobe` to get the embedded date and title metadata and write it with `eyeD3` or `id3v2`:

   ```
   eyeD3 --title "$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format_tags=DATE -of csv=p=0 "input.webm") $(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format_tags=title -of csv=p=0 "input.webm")" output.mp3
   ```

   `ffmpeg` can write ID3v2 tags, but it has [some issues](https://superuser.com/a/1588252/110524), so `eyeD3` is recommended instead.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a script like that:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# File names will have following format "yyyymmdd Title.webm"
/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl -o "%(upload_date)s %(title)s.%(ext)s" --write-annotations --download-archive ".archive" --add-metadata -f "bestaudio[ext=webm]" -i "$ChannelPath"
for name in *.webm; do
  # Recode to MP3
  /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i "$name" -acodec libmp3lame "${name%.*}.mp3"
  # Get title from WEBM tag
  video_title=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format_tags=TITLE -of csv=p=0 "$name")
  # We know file name format, lets extract timestamp from it
  timestamp=${name%%[[:space:]]*}
  # Concatenate timestamp with internal title
  eyeD3 -t "$timestamp $video_title" "${name%.*}.mp3"
done
```